# Was column ever equal to x in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a dataset that looks similar to this:

```
UniqueRef   Description       Date
    1                  Y    14/04/2020
    2                  Y    02/04/2020
    2                  X    07/04/2020
    2                  Y    12/04/2020
    3                  X    16/04/2020
    3                  Y    24/04/2020
    4                  Y    24/04/2020
    4                  X    21/04/2020
    4                  X    14/05/2020
    4                  Y    23/03/2020
```

I want to check if the description was ever equal to X, grouped by unique ref. I would also like it to have a separate column for the date in which description was X. If the unique ref has been X more than once then the date would be the most recent.

which would give an output similar to:

```
UniqueRef   Description            Date        Check     CheckDate
        1                  Y    14/04/2020       No          NA
        2                  Y    02/04/2020       Yes         07/04/2020
        2                  X    07/04/2020       Yes         07/04/2020
        2                  Y    12/04/2020       Yes         07/04/2020
        3                  X    16/04/2020       Yes         16/04/2020
        3                  Y    24/04/2020       Yes         16/04/2020
        4                  Y    24/04/2020       Yes         14/05/2020
        4                  X    21/04/2020       Yes         14/05/2020
        4                  X    14/05/2020       Yes         14/05/2020
        4                  Y    23/03/2020       Yes         14/05/2020
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when description = 'X' then 'Y' else 'N' end) over (partition by uniqueref) as ever_x,
       max(case when description = 'X' then date end) over (partition by uniqueref) as x_date
from t;
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a couple of windowed conditional aggregates gets you what you're after here:

```
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT V.UniqueRef,
           V.[Description],
           CONVERT(date,V.[Date],103) AS [Date]
    FROM (VALUES(1,'Y','14/04/2020'),
                (2,'Y','02/04/2020'),
                (2,'X','07/04/2020'),
                (2,'Y','12/04/2020'),
                (3,'X','16/04/2020'),
                (3,'Y','24/04/2020'),
                (4,'Y','24/04/2020'),
                (4,'X','21/04/2020'),
                (4,'X','14/05/2020'),
                (4,'Y','23/03/2020'))V(UniqueRef,[Description],[Date]))
SELECT YT.UniqueRef,
       YT.[Description],
       YT.[Date],
       MAX(CASE YT.[Description] WHEN 'X' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.UniqueRef) AS [Check], --CHECK is a reserved keyword, i suggest a different name
       MAX(CASE YT.[Description] WHEN 'X' THEN YT.[Date] END) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.UniqueRef) AS CheckDate
FROM YourTable YT;
```